# Cannot stop javascript function with conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, boolean

I have a fixed top navigation bar that uses a javascript function to shrink in size along with changing a couple other styles when the user scrolls past a certain anchor point. I also have a mobile hamburger icon that expands the navigation into a fullscreen menu for mobile. I would like the javascript function for shrinking the top nav to stop working whenever I click on the hamburger (opening the menu) and to resume when clicked again (closing the menu), however I am not able to get the scroll function to start or stop.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
<script>
var win = $(window),
    nw = $('.navBgWrapper'),
    sw = $('.scrollWaypoint'),
    pos = sw.offset().top;
var sticky = function(){
            if (win.scrollTop() > pos) {
                nw.addClass('navBgWrapperChange');
                $('.vjLogoWhite').removeClass('logoGo');
                $('.vjLogoGreen').addClass('logoGo');

                $('.navLink').removeClass('linkTop');
                $('.navLink').addClass('linkScroll');
                $('.navContent').on('hover', '.navLink', function () {
                    $('.navLink').removeClass('hoverTop');
                    $('.navLink').addClass('hoverScroll');
                });

            }
            else {
                nw.removeClass('navBgWrapperChange')
                $('.vjLogoGreen').removeClass('logoGo');
                $('.vjLogoWhite').addClass('logoGo');

                $('.navLink').removeClass('linkScroll');
                $('.navLink').addClass('linkTop');
                $('.navContent').on('hover', '.navLink', function () {
                    $('.navLink').removeClass('hoverScroll');
                    $('.navLink').addClass('hoverTop');
                });
            }
    }

//burger script
var sc = true;
$('.menu').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    if (!sc) {
        sc = true;
    } else {
        sc = false;
    }
    $('.menu-item').toggleClass('menuItemToggle');
    $('.navMenuBg').toggleClass('navMenuBgGo');
    $('.vjLogoWhite').toggleClass('logoGo');
    $('.vjLogoGreen').toggleClass('logoGo');
    $('.navLinks').toggleClass('navLinksShow');
});
</script>
<script>
if (sc) {
    win.scroll(sticky);
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can just use `true` and `false`; you don't have to construct Boolean instances. Also it's *usually* a bad idea to directly compare to boolean values; just use `if (sc)` or `if (!sc)`.

Comment: I did originally, but constructed Boolean to see if that would help to no avail...

Comment: Well where's the code that actually *uses* the `sc` variable? All that happens in the code you posted is that the variable is set to one thing or the other.

Comment: very sorry, missed the last part, added the bottom code where sc is used and also made changes as suggested by you.

Comment: Ah. Well I think you need to be checking the flag *inside* the scroll event handler. Once you've set up the handler, it's set up; nothing's going to check the flag.  From inside the handler, however, you can just check the flag and return if it's false (or true; whichever means that you shouldn't scroll).

Comment: That worked, thank you so much, I still don't understand why the flag needs to be inside of the handler and why it always executes, but here is the working code:

`var sticky = function(){ if (!sc) { return; } else {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments of question for details, thanks Pointy.

```
var sticky = function(){ if (!sc) { return; } else {...}
```